# Use CFBundleCopyExecutableURL to see if an application is executable in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

Could someone tell me if simply using CFBundleCopyExecutableURL(CFBundleRef) as in the psuedo code:

```
if (CFBundleCopyExecutableURL(MyCFBundleRef) == NULL) {NSLog(@"This app is not supported on this system")};
```

is, in fact, enough to confirm whether an app can be run on the local hardware?

A portion of my app presents the user with a list of the Applications folder on their OSX10.7 system but I'd like to allow them to drag and drop other apps that are (deftly!) placed somewhere like the Desktop. It'd be handy if I can double check that they haven't tried to pull in an old Universal application or suchlike that was left on their system through the OS upgrade to Lion...

I've used some example code that Apple supply for examining headers and current architecture but that fails with a couple of apps I've tried it on: the code returns false despite the computer being able to run the programme. To see this code search the Xcode doc's with 'checkexecutablearchitecture' the sample code is shown in results. I'm optimistically hoping that the code's out of date and the above simple check is enough nowadays.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I think I've found a solution - certainly for my scenario. I'm now using a small method as below:

```
-(BOOL)isURLExecutable:(NSURL*)appURL;
{
    CFURLRef bundleURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL, (uint8_t*)[[appURL path] UTF8String], strlen((const char *)(uint8_t*)[[appURL path] UTF8String]), true);
    CFArrayRef archArrayRef = CFBundleCopyExecutableArchitecturesForURL(bundleURL);

    BOOL isI386 = [(NSArray*)archArrayRef containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCFBundleExecutableArchitectureX86_64]] || [(NSArray*)archArrayRef containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCFBundleExecutableArchitectureI386]];

    if (archArrayRef != NULL) {
        if (isI386) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

If there's anyone who can advise me of a better way, please do!

Todd.

Comment: I think the approach is reasonable, although hard-coding a set of supported architectures is fragile. By the way, why take `appURL`, get a path `NSString`, get a UTF-8 C-style string, and use that to create a `CFURL`? An `NSURL` is a `CFURL` already. Also, you can create an `NSBundle` for the URL and use the `-executableArchitectures` method. That would simplify the code further.

Comment: Thanks Ken, much appreciated. The code was 'morphed' from when I was using Apple's example code and I was lazy in not re-writing. Actually, that was probably a complete false economy.